# CakePHP multisite (like WPMU + domain mapping)... possible?

Tags: cakephp, dns

So I'm just starting to play with CakePHP and was wondering if the following was possible:

A single install of Cake, with a super admin login. Then, admins that have access to specified "sub sites", and the ability to create/edit content and users on those sub sites. Finally, the ability to map domain names (not subdomains, but unique domains) to the routes; so instead of mysite.com/subsite/posts/1 it would just be newdomain.com/posts/1

Essentially, I'm looking to replicate the experience of using Wordpress Multi-user (with domain mapping).

Is this possible? If so, what should I be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can even use the same set of code and just configure certain domains to point to the code. Then in the code base, tie a domain ID to each user and the content so it knows where it belongs. You can have admin users belong to all domains. Then when you add regular users, you can specify what domain they belong to.

You could establish the domain checking in the Config/bootstrap.php and then set the configuration for the domain like so:

```
Configure::write('domain_id', 'someDomainSpecificID');
```

Then you only have to maintain one set of code and one database from many domains.

If the domains have to be physically separate, you could set up one location for the ADMIN users (single database) and run everything against that.

There are many ways you could architect it, it just depends on what your specific needs are. It sounds like a cool project though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! For this project one code base makes sense since all the "sub sites" will be identical. Keeping it DRY and all that!

Comment: Then yeah, it should be simple to do. You can even setup the AppController so that it changes the Layout on the fly in the beforeRender(). $this->layout = 'site1'; etc.

Comment: Awesome! You're a pro star. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify: this answer is for WPMu-like on cake, right? @ChuckBurgess Do you know anything about domain mapping on cakephp?

Comment: Correct. However, I am not familiar with domain mapping on CakePHP. Especially with the pending release of CakePHP 3.x.